# Gridview not showing the records when i input the specific record name

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

hope you all are fine

i am new on asp.net i am facing a problem when i input the data in textbox and the result related to that textbox can not showing in gridview popup.
here is my code below

```
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Button1").live("click", function () {
        $("#popup").dialog({
            title: "Displaying GridView Data",
            width: 600,
            buttons: {
            //            if you want close button use below code
            //                Close: function () {
            //                    $(this).dialog('close');
            //                }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>   
    <div id="popup" style ="display:none">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="OpprId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CardCode" HeaderText="CardCode" 
                SortExpression="CardCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OpprId" HeaderText="OpprId" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="OpprId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SlpCode" HeaderText="SlpCode" 
                SortExpression="SlpCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PredDate" HeaderText="PredDate" 
                SortExpression="PredDate" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDataBaseConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [CardCode], [OpprId], [SlpCode], [PredDate] FROM [OOPR] WHERE ([CardCode] = @CardCode)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="CardCode" PropertyName="Text" 
                Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
     </div>
       </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Kindly help, your help will be highly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is kind of incomplete. I don't see the `textbox1` control. Also You have gridview in a div which has `"style=display:none";`

Please share your complete code or enough code so someone can understand and help you out.

**UPDATE**

Add

```
$( "#popup" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
```

before the code

```
$("#Button1").live("click", function ()
```

Also remove the style on `#popup` div.

More details are here  https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#entry-examples

Hope it should work.